# SQL select inside select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables.

```
person{personid,name, etc}
bid{bidid,personid,etc}
rating{ratingid,bidid,rating}
```

A person gets the rating after the bid is accepted by customers. So `1 bid = 1 rating`.
And then the person bids another order, but the rating won't show up.

I already tried:

```
SELECT a.namausaha,ROUND(AVG(c.rating)) AS rating,a.kota,a.kontak,b.bidprice,a.mitraid
FROM tb_mitra a
JOIN tb_bid b ON b.mitraid=a.mitraid
LEFT JOIN tb_rating c ON c.bidid=b.bidid
WHERE b.orderid='OD004' AND b.statusbidid='1'
GROUP BY a.mitraid
```

but it doesn't work.

How to do it? I want to show the rating for every person.

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: @fa06 i want to show the rating for every person

Comment: @cegfault not error. but the rating wont show up

Comment: Can you post what output you received, and what  output you were expecting?

Comment: @cegfault okay. i add the image.

Comment: Your `select` and `group by` are inconsistent.

Comment: I consider a bug of MySQL that columns not on the `GROUP BY` can show up in the `SELECT`. The MySQL engine ends up picking one of them randomly. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Some `rating` return `null` due to `left join`

Try this

```
SELECT a.name,
  ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN c.rating IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE c.rating END )) AS rating,
  a.etc,b.etc,a.personid
FROM person a
JOIN bid b ON b.personid=a.personid
LEFT JOIN rating c ON c.bidid=b.bidid
GROUP BY a.personid
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30ba91/5)

Comment: If he/she wants the ratings for all persons, then you should do a `LEFT JOIN` on `b`.

Comment: Also, only the columns in the `GROUP BY` can show up in non-aggregated form in the `SELECT`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried that, but the guy who have 4 rating become 3. and the guy who doesnt have rating become 1 rating.

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, i want the rating for all person. the person who dont have rating should show up too with 0 rating.

Comment: @RisliAzis, have you solve the rating problem? or are you still trying?